# Grouping occupancies by residence, occupant and date range in Microsoft SQL Server 2008, Quicker way to do it

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am being provided a table of dates people occupied certain properties with multiple dates for each person at each property, and need to group them by person, property, min date from and max date to.

It is complicated by people who have moved from an address, then back into the 
address after living somewhere else for a while. These need to be recorded as separate occupancies.

There are some occurrences where a person may be recorded as occupying multiple 
addresses at the same time.

For example, the data I have been provided may have 5 lines for Bob:

Bob 20 Street A from 1/1/2015 to 31/3/2015

Bob 20 Street A from 1/4/2015 to 30/4/2015

Bob 10 Street B from 1/5/2015 to 31/5/2015

Bob 10 Street B from 1/6/2015 to 30-6-2015

Bob 20 Street A from 1/7/2015 to 31/7/2015.

I need to summarise this as

Bob 20 Street A from 1/1/2015 to 30/4/2015
Bob 10 Street B from 1/5/2015 to 30/6/2015
Bob 20 Street A from 1/7/2015 to 31/7/2015

The way I have done it is to put it into a table variable ordered by Name, Date From and Address, then adding a extra column incrementing a row number. This works, but takes far too long on the large data set to be usable.

Below is the code I have used:

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempA') is not null
    drop table #tempA

go

create table #tempA (
    Name nvarchar(20)
    ,HouseNumber int
    ,StreetName nvarchar(50)
    ,AddressID int
    ,DateFrom date
    ,DateTo date null
    )

insert into #tempA values
    ('Bob',20,'Street A',1,'2015-01-01','2015-03-31')
    ,('Bob',20,'Street A',1,'2015-04-01','2015-04-30')
    ,('Bob',10,'Street B',4,'2015-05-01','2015-05-31')
    ,('Bob',10,'Street B',4,'2015-06-01','2015-06-30')
    ,('Bob',20,'Street A',1,'2015-07-01','2015-07-31')
    ,('Fred',25,'Street A',7,'2015-05-01','2015-06-30')
    ,('Jo',20,'Street A',1,'2015-04-01','2015-06-30')
    ,('Jo',15,'Street C',13,'2015-08-01',null)
    ,('Fred',30,'Street D',15,'2015-07-01',null)
    ,('Fred',25,'Street A',7,'2015-08-01','2015-08-02')

select *
from #tempA

Declare @Count int
    ,@AddressID int
    ,@total_Count int
    ,@Count_Partition int
    ,@Previous_ID int

Set @Count = 1
Set @Count_Partition = 1

declare @tblA table (ID int identity(1,1)
    ,Name nvarchar(20)
    ,HouseNumber int
    ,StreetName nvarchar(50)
    ,AddressID int
    ,DateFrom date
    ,DateTo date null
    ,RN int
    ,unique nonclustered (rn,id)
    )

insert into @tblA (
    Name
    ,HouseNumber
    ,StreetName
    ,AddressID
    ,DateFrom
    ,DateTo
    )
    select Name
    ,HouseNumber
    ,StreetName
    ,AddressID
    ,DateFrom
    ,isnull(DateTo,'4000-12-31')
    from #tempA
    order by Name
        ,DateFrom
        ,AddressID

Select @total_Count = ISNULL(MAX(ID),0)
from @TblA

While @Count < = @total_Count
    Begin
        Select @AddressID = AddressID 
        From @TblA
        Where ID = @Count

        If @Count = 1
            Set @Previous_ID = @AddressID

        If @Previous_ID != @AddressID
            Set @Count_Partition = @Count_Partition + 1

        update @TblA
        Set RN = @Count_Partition
        Where ID = @Count

        Set @Previous_ID = @AddressID
        Set @Count = @Count + 1
    End

select a.Name
    ,a.HouseNumber
    ,a.StreetName
    ,a.AddressID
    ,MIN(b.DateFrom) as DateFrom
    ,case when MAX(b.DateTo) = '4000-12-31' then null else  MAX(b.DateTo) end as DateTo

from @tblA a
left join @tblA b
    on a.RN =  b.RN

group by a.Name
    ,a.HouseNumber
    ,a.StreetName
    ,a.AddressID
    ,a.RN

order by a.Name
    ,MIN(b.DateFrom)
    ,MAX(b.DateTo)
```

Can anyone suggest a way to speed it up, or a better way of doing it that will be quicker?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used ROW_NUMBER to order the data and a Common Table Expression (CTE) to associate the rows to one another. It should speed this up a bit but remember to bear in mind the MAXRECURSION value associated with a CTE.

Assumed that the rows are associated if the dates are 1 day apart (DateTo + 1 Day = DateFrom). See comment in the SQL.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempA') is not null
    drop table #tempA
go

create table #tempA (
    Name nvarchar(20)
    ,HouseNumber int
    ,StreetName nvarchar(50)
    ,AddressID int
    ,DateFrom date
    ,DateTo date null
    )

insert into #tempA values
    ('Bob',20,'Street A',1,'2015-01-01','2015-03-31')
    ,('Bob',20,'Street A',1,'2015-04-01','2015-04-30')
    ,('Bob',10,'Street B',4,'2015-05-01','2015-05-31')
    ,('Bob',10,'Street B',4,'2015-06-01','2015-06-30')
    ,('Bob',20,'Street A',1,'2015-07-01','2015-07-31')
    ,('Fred',25,'Street A',7,'2015-05-01','2015-06-30')
    ,('Jo',20,'Street A',1,'2015-04-01','2015-06-30')
    ,('Jo',15,'Street C',13,'2015-08-01',null)
    ,('Fred',30,'Street D',15,'2015-07-01',null)
    ,('Fred',25,'Street A',7,'2015-08-01','2015-08-02')

DECLARE @GroupedTable table (
    GroupedTableId int identity(1,1),
    Position int,
    Name nvarchar(20),
    HouseNumber int,
    StreetName nvarchar(50),
    AddressID int,
    DateFrom date,
    DateTo date null
)

-- use row number to group data by name and address id
insert into @GroupedTable
(Position, Name, HouseNumber, StreetName, AddressID, DateFrom, DateTo)
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by Name, AddressID order by DateFrom),
    Name, HouseNumber, StreetName, AddressID, DateFrom, DateTo
from #tempA

-- use CTE to associate rows with one another based on DateTo and DateFrom
;with cte (GroupedTableId, Position, Name, HouseNumber, StreetName, AddressID, DateFrom, DateTo, RootDate, ParentID)
as
(
    select GroupedTableId, Position, Name, HouseNumber, StreetName, AddressID, DateFrom, DateTo, DateFrom, CONVERT(INT, NULL)
    from @GroupedTable
    where Position = 1
    UNION ALL
    select g.GroupedTableId, g.Position, g.Name, g.HouseNumber, g.StreetName, g.AddressID, g.DateFrom, g.DateTo, 
        -- ASSUMING MONTHS ARE 1 DAY APART AND THAT EXTENDS THE STAY AT ADDRESS
        CASE WHEN DATEADD(D,1,c.DateTo) = g.DateFrom THEN c.DateFrom ELSE g.DateFrom END, 
        CASE WHEN DATEADD(D,1,c.DateTo) = g.DateFrom THEN c.GroupedTableId ELSE NULL END
    from @GroupedTable g
    inner join cte c on c.Position = g.Position -1 and c.Name = g.Name and c.AddressID = g.AddressID
)

select Name, HouseNumber, StreetName, AddressID, RootDate as StartDate, DateTo from cte
where GroupedTableId not in (
    select ParentID from cte
    where ParentID is not null
)
order by Name, RootDate
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good. Will have a play with it on the full dataset and see how much time it saves.